# Is there an equivalent to aircraft ATA100 numbering system for Spacecraft?

Tags: engineering

The [ATA100 numbering system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATA_100) is frequently used in aircraft as a common referencing standard.

> "The unique aspect of the chapter numbers is its relevance for all aircraft. Thus a chapter reference number for a Boeing 747 will be the same for other Boeing aircraft, a BAe 125 and Airbus Aircraft. Examples of this include Oxygen (Chapter 35), Electrical Power (Chapter 24) and Doors (Chapter 52)."- Wikipedia

For instance, ATA100 reference code 27-50 implies the chapter Flight Controls, section Flaps.

**Is there an equivalent numbering system for spacecraft and their systems?**

Comment: ATA 100 is used on aircraft. It defines how aircraft are maintained using approved manuals. All repairs io aircraft MUST HAVE an approved CMM (component maintenance manual)
Space shuttle is a military aircraft. I have never came across CMM S for shuttle. You can look under DMWR's (military cmm's).

Comment: Space shuttle was *not* a *military aircraft*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with ATA100, but shuttle had what seems to be an analogous numbering system. It was used in telemetry IDs, and I think in work packages as well. I doubt it was used in other spacecraft.

[image]

Comment: Cool! I think spacecraft might be too bespoke to make a cross-reference system worthwhile. Would this document be publicly available? :)

Comment: I don't think it is. You can see some examples of the numbering convention in use, though, in the CAIB Report on the Columbia accident (http://s3.amazonaws.com/akamai.netstorage/anon.nasa-global/CAIB/CAIB_medres_full.pdf), page 65 for instance.  V09T.... is shown, which decodes as an Orbiter TPS temperature, as is V12G..., an Orbiter Wing Box strain gauge.

Answer (score 2):

Spacecraft tracked by NASA's Deep Space Network rely on SPICE, a software library for observation geometry information. SPICE itself maintains a list of *semi-official* spacecraft (and natural body) identifiers, the [*NAIF Integer ID codes*](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/FORTRAN/req/naif_ids.html).

The NAIF Integer ID codes do not apply to Earth-orbiting spacecraft. Instead, the North American Aerospace Defense Command (NORAD) a[ssigns its own identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_Catalog_Number). NAIF maps them as `SPICE_ID = -100000 - NORAD_ID`.

Other countries may have their own internal designations, and the [CCSDS is trying to standardize the methodology](https://public.ccsds.org/SpacecraftID.aspx).

The answer to your question would be *no, there is nothing like ATA1000*. Instead, there are many ad hoc numbering systems aiming to consolidate.

Within SPICE, specific instruments are numbered according to the spacecraft:

`NAIF instrument code = (s/c code)*(1000) - instrument number`

In the linked page they cite as example the instruments of Voyager 2:

`-32000 -> Instrument Scan Platform 
-32001 -> ISSNA (Imaging science narrow angle camera) 
-32002 -> ISSWA (Imaging science wide angle camera) 
-32003 -> PPS (Photopolarimeter) 
-32004 -> UVSAG (Ultraviolet Spectrometer, Airglow port) 
-32005 -> UVSOCC (Ultraviolet Spectrometer, Occultation port) 
-32006 -> IRIS (Infrared Interferometer Spectrometer and Radiometer)`